# Tricky probability bound

Tags: probability-theory

Here's an easy-looking probability theory problem that so far has defied my attempts at solving it:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real independent identically distributed random variables. Prove that

$$
Pr(|X-Y| \le 2) \leq 3Pr(|X-Y| \le 1)
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is certainly not recreational-mathematics, is called the 123 theorem and is due to [Noga Alon and Raphael Yuster](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/publications.html). The full statement is:

> For every $b> a> 0$ and for every two independent identically distributed real random variables $X$ and $Y$, $P[|X − Y | ≤ b] < (2⌈b/a ⌉ − 1)P[|X − Y | ≤ a]$. This is tight for all admissible pairs $(a, b)$.